# What happens when I kill a script that was started at boot without the &?

Tags: boot, python, process, kill

I have a ARM64 board running Ubuntu 18 and I wrote a .sh script that is executed at boot (with rc.local):

```
create_ap [...] &
taskset -c 0 python my_script.py &
```

`create_ap` refers to [this](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) project. The python script is a multiprocessing script involving camera (OpenCV) and microphone (PyAudio).
If I log into the board via SSH and I run `pkill -9 python`, the python script and its child processes correctly end.

One day I forgot to put the `&` at the end of the second line (the python one). The script started at boot as usual, but when I logged into the board and I ran `pkill -9 python`, I immediately got disconnected and the hotspot disappeared. What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Why would you ever want to kill "python" and not only the pid to the process?  How many python process where active when you used pkill? Just this one? Or a dozen others that also got killed in the process?

Comment: the script that I run at boot generates other processes and I want to kill them all and not just the original one.

Comment: If you kill the original one, the child processes should be killed as well.

Comment: Do `pgrep python` to list the PIDs that `pkill` will kill. Read `man pkill`.